# Positioning problems

Tags: html, css

I've encountered this problem in which three of my anchors are not allowing the other three to get their right position but when I change the position to absolute it works fine but the three anchors merged with each other, is there a way that I can make this problem go away?

Any help will be appreciated

```
.R-news {
   width: 18rem;
   height: 18rem;
   margin:.5rem;
   background-color: #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #fff, 1px 3px 4px #333;
   float:right;
   clear:both;
}
.R-news img {
   height: 11rem;
   width:18rem;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gr84a/2/)

Comment: I don't understand what you problem is… could you give more details of what you want?

Comment: I'm confused, where do you want `.R-news` to be displayed?

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your right floats **before** your other content in your markup. You also have to make sure the widths don't collide with each other. Check out my example.

```
<article class="R-news">...</article>
<article class="c-news">...</article>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gr84a/10/